# Validate the website URL address doesn't have path using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to validate a URL address included within a text. This URL should has the following structure.

```
<http<s>://>www<.sub-domain*>.domain-name.TLD<.ccTLD><:port-number></>
```

Where <> means optional and * means zero or more.

As it is shown, the parser should accept the following.

1. http or https and both of them are optional.
2. www have to be accepted.
3. Accepting zero or more sub-domains
4. Domain-name have to be accepted.
5. Accepting the Top Level Domain(TLD) and country code TLD if it is exist.
6. Accepting the port number if it is available.
7. Accepting the end back slash(/)
   if it is there.

The output should be either the address (if it is accepted) or False.

This is the written code in python3.7.

```
import re

s=['https://www.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone/',
   'jzd https://www.google.edu sdfklg','sdj http://google.com jkdf',
   'https://web.vortex.data.m','sjdfn www.google.com.au','www.google.com/','https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443',
   'http://www.msn.com:80','google.com','(www.google.co.in)']

pattern=r'((http(s)?:\/\/)?www\.)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.][a-z0-9]+)*\.(com?|edu|gov|int|net|org|biz|info)(\.[a-z]{2})?(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/)?'

def match_URL(pat,line):
    try:
        return re.search(pat,line).group()
    except:
        return False

for i in range(len(s):
    print(i,"- ",s[i]," --> ",match_URL(pattern,s[i]))
```

The expected results of the addresses listed in s are:

> 0-    https://www.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone/    Fail
>
> 1-    jzd https://www.google.edu sdfklg           Pass
>
> 2-    sdj http://google.com jkdf                  Fail
>
> 3-    https://web.vortex.data.m                   Fail
>
> 4-    sjdfn www.google.com.au                     Pass
>
> 5-    www.google.com/                             Pass
>
> 6-    https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443     Fail
>
> 7-    http://www.msn.com:80                       Pass
>
> 8-    google.com                                  Fail
>
> 9-    (www.google.co.in)                          Pass

This is the result.

```
0 -  https://www.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone/  -->  https://www.yahoo.com/
1 -  jzd https://www.google.edu sdfklg  -->  https://www.google.edu
2 -  sdj http://google.com jkdf  -->  False
3 -  https://web.vortex.data.m  -->  False
4 -  sjdfn www.google.com.au  -->  www.google.com.au
5 -  www.google.com/  -->  www.google.com/
6 -  https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443  -->  False
7 -  http://www.msn.com:80  -->  http://www.msn.com:80
8 -  google.com  -->  False
9 -  (www.google.co.in)  -->  www.google.co.in
```

All the results are they expected unless the first one the parser should return "False" since the matching pattern should not accept a path after the domain.

My question: what can be added to the matching pattern that does not accept the URL that has path after last back slash?

Comment: You should consider putting the values of `s` into a vertical list and commenting pass/fail. Right now it is really hard to tell what you expect from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Without going crazy and trying to [validate all TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) nor port numbers then something like this would work:

```
(https?:\/\/)?                # optionally start with http(s)://
(?:[a-z]+(?:-+[a-z]+)*\.){2,} # require 2 or more instances of chars and dashes followed by a period
[a-z]+                        # TLD check
(:\d+)?                       # optional port number
\/?                           # optional traling slash
```

https://regex101.com/r/OUxQvj/4

Comment: It is still not fully address all my instances. For example, the provided regex pattern should not accept the first example. Also,  the second one form the end is accepted and it should not.

Comment: @aneesal-najjar See my request for clarification comment on your original question. After you provide that information then I will consider updating my regex.

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty much similar to the OP's with some simplifications. First, the regex is started off with `(?i)` to make the search case insensitive. Second, and most importantly, the regex has a terminating negative lookahead `(?!(\/|\w))`, which says that the preceding portion of the regex should only match if the if is not followed by either a `/` or a word character.

If you only want the domain name, such as www.yahoo.com, then:

`return re.search(pat,line.group(2))`

```
import re

s=['https://www.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone/',
   'jzd https://www.google.edu sdfklg','sdj http://google.com jkdf',
   'https://web.vortex.data.m','sjdfn www.google.com.au','www.google.com/','https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443',
   'http://www.msn.com:80','google.com','(www.google.co.in)']

pattern=r'(?i)((?:https?:\/\/)?(www(\.[a-z0-9\-]+)*\.(com?|edu|gov|int|net|org|biz|info)(\.[a-z]{2})?)(?::[0-9]{1,5})?(\/)?)(?!(\/|\w))'

def match_URL(pat,line):
    try:
        return re.search(pat,line).group()
    except:
        return False

for i in s:
    print(i," --> ",match_URL(pattern,i))
```

Prints:

```
https://www.yahoo.com/news/apple-iphone/  -->  False
jzd https://www.google.edu sdfklg  -->  https://www.google.edu
sdj http://google.com jkdf  -->  False
https://web.vortex.data.m  -->  False
sjdfn www.google.com.au  -->  www.google.com.au
www.google.com/  -->  www.google.com/
https://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net:443  -->  False
http://www.msn.com:80  -->  http://www.msn.com:80
google.com  -->  False
(www.google.co.in)  -->  www.google.co.in
```

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/OawcV8)